# How to declare repository details outside build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am using `repositories{}` block to declare repositories for dependency resolution  in build.gradle file. Is there any way to declare repositories outside build.gradle file so that I don't have to declare for every other projects.

I am coming from maven background where we could declare repositories in settings.xml in .m2 folder.

Please advice.

Comment: I figured this out later. The answer to this is declare to respository details in gradle.properties file as global variable in your .gradle folder in user directory. You can use those global variables in your build.gradle for all local projects.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your dependencies are an important part of your build. It is one of the many elements that help provide reproducible builds. Maven assumes that a given version of a dependency is the same in all repositories. Sadly, this is not true.

So it is natural to declare repositories in each Gradle build.
This can be externalized by having the declarations come from an [external script which is applied](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) in your project.

And that script should rely on the `allprojects` block to make sure repositories are added to all the projects of a multi project build.

Comment: I believe there still should be a away to provide repositories outside the build.gradle in local, given that normally in an organization, we generally have very standard respository structure for dependency resolution and declaring those repositories in every build.gradle file does not make sense. it is kind of creating hard dependencies on each project. Also, moving in dev region, dependency resolution can be taken care by Jenkins in build job config which is again outside build.gradle.

Comment: I'm not sure having the repository hard-coded in the code repository is a good idea either. This can cause problems when repositories are unavailable or disappear altogether (e.g. Codehaus). Being able to specify a repository within an organisation is actually good for reproducibility too: you're not so depend on external factors once the library is cached. (Also, Maven/Gradle seem to have a tendency to "leak" the name of libraries you're attempting to download, even internal names, which can be an issue.) At least being able to override with local config would be good.